# Reading Input into Array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to read a series of 8 integers from a file into an array then display those integers. I keep getting a segmentation fault the third time around, and I can't quite figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
struct aStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    ...
};

typedef struct aStruct myStruct; 

while(fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, file) != NULL) {
    int myArray[8] = {0};
    char* val = strtok (line," ,\n\t\r");
    while (val != NULL)
    {
        myArray[i] = atoi(val);
        i++;
        val = strtok (NULL, " ,\n\t\r");
    }

    myStruct foo;

    foo.a = myArray[0];
    foo.b = myArray[1];
            ...
}
```

The input file is structured like so:

```
0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0
1, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0
2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0
3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0
4, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

When tested with:

```
printf("myArray[0]: %d ", myArray[0]);
```

I get an odd output of `0 0`

Where I believe it should be `0 1`. Am I not initializing something correctly, or is my `new` syntax incorrect for the struct? I've tried a few different combinations, cant quite figure it out.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`) and **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`); also `new` is a C++ keyword (not a C one). So you should tag your question as `C++` (and improve your code to be more genuine C++, probably using `std::vector` ..). Also show more code, notably declaration of `myStruct` ...

Comment: Sorry. I was unaware that `new` is a C++ keyword. I am trying to write this all in C, so perhaps I should switch that around.

Comment: Then your code is not C and should not compile with a standard C compiler (unless if `new` is some very weird macro, you should show its definition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem here is in uninitialized or non reset `i` variable. Adding `i = 0` inside your while-loop might help.

```
while(fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, file) != NULL) {
    i = 0; // <<< reseting array index
    int myArray[8] = {0};
    char* val = strtok (line," ,\n\t\r");
    while (val != NULL)
    {
        //...
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! I'm blind. I knew it was something small. Thank you!